# Combining Regex Patterns from various Urls

Tags: javascript, regex, url, regex-group

I have the following urls and I am trying to combine them into one pattern rather than multiple. How should I write this? The conditional I'm writing needs to test if it matches users or cases or both or all three, etc..

```
const casesUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/cases\/[\w-]+/g 
const usersUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/users\/[\w-]+/g 
const lawfirmsUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/lawfirms\/[\w-]+/g
```

Is there a better way to do this than writing multiple conditional statements like below?

```
if (usersUrl.test(response.config.url) ) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
```

I have tried doing something similar here with no luck:

```
const regexUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/(users|cases)\/[\w-]+/g
```

Comment: So the individual regexes worked, but with the alternation it did not? Like `const regexUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/(?:users|cases|lawfirms)\/[\w-]+/g`

Comment: What you showed should work, please create a simple test case showing what was the invalid input. The regex you have works against URLs like `/api/v1/users/an-id` and `/api/v1/cases/an-id`

Comment: You can put capture groups around the different words to use as flags to tell what matched `/api/v1/(?:(case)|(user)|(lawfirm))s/[\w-]+` thats the best you could do. For example `if group(1) matched, else if group(2)` etc .. But it does do an important thing, it decreases the load thus is performant.

Comment: I found this was an issue with the .test() method maintaining state so by moving my variables I was able to get the first comment to work! 
`const regexUrl =  /\/api\/v1\/(?:users|cases|lawfirms)\/[\w-]+/g`